# Server not accessible publicly

Tags: routes, portforwarding

I can't access my Web Server (running Apache 2.4 on Windows XP) from outside.

I have already forwarded Port 80 from my router:

[image: Port Forwarding (Router)]

I had also opened Port 80 from Windows Firewall, and add an exception to it:

[image: Port Forwarding (Firewall)]

I have found a routing solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/260014/access-internal-ip-using-public-ip#answer-888558).  Does this work?

But, I can access my site from within my network only.  When I connect to other networks, I cannot access my site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a residential internet connection. Depending on your ISP, such as Cox (my *beloved* ISP), they may choose to [block your public http port](http://www.cox.com/residential/support/internet/article.cox?articleId=cacf82f0-6407-11df-ccef-000000000000) as an incentive to get you to upgrade to a costly business internet connection.

You can check by running [network map](https://nmap.org/). Once installed, then run the command from somewhere away from home outside your network:

```
nmap -Pn -p 80 192.168.0.1
```

and change the 192.168.0.1 IP to [your **public** IP](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what%27s%20my%20public%20ip). With luck, you'll get an open scan like this:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-03-22 22:17 CDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.1
Host is up (0.0028s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.13 seconds
```

Otherwise, you'll get a filtered scan like this:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-03-22 22:19 CDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.1
Host is up.
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.58 seconds
```

In this case, then others can still reach you on a non-blocked port. 8080 is a popular choice. you will need to adjust the settings in your router to port forward map your incoming external port 8080 to your internal port 80 of the **internal** IP of your server.

**Edit:** I see from your screenshot that you cannot forward one port to a different port, at least on this screen. Check your other screens and search for how to do it with your model of router. It might not be possible with that router - I once had a cheap Netgear router that didn't support that basic function. In that event, you will need to change or add the port that apache listens on, their [documentation is here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html).

Once you have that setup correctly, then the world will be able to reach your site at `http://192.168.0.1:8080`, again making sure to use your **public** IP and not the 192.168.

I borrowed this snippet from [another answer of mine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746994/make-my-apache2-server-public/749180#749180)

Comment: More info:  I'm using a router "Hitron CGN-AP".